# How to find all Salesforce records with a specific WhoId?

Tags: rest-api, rest

I have a Lead or Contact. I want to find all of the Accounts and Opportunities for that specific Lead or Contact. Is that possible? What would the query look like?

Comment: WhatId is a field on Activities (Tasks and Events). Are you really asking about finding related activities for a given contact or lead, but that is not what your question is currently asking. You may want to rephrase.

Comment: Removed the confusing parts, I guess.

Comment: Based on your edits, here is my new comment: lead has no standard relationship to Account nor Opportunity and has nothing to do with a WhoId. I'm still not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I mean, that was part of my confusion, too. I didn't know that Leads couldn't be associated with Opportunities.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually going to answer my own question in case someone else was wondering.

First, Leads cannot be associated with Opportunities, so it's not possible to answer that part of the question. Taking that out, we can still get all the Opportunities for a given Contact:

`SELECT Opportunity.Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id in (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE ContactId = 'YOUR_CONTACT_ID')`

I was under the impression that Leads and Contacts were grouped together all the time because of the way the API groups them together in a WhoId. I didn't realize that Leads cannot belong to an Opportunity.

Comment: Based on this answer, your question should read something more like "How do I find all of the related opportunities for a given Contact Id associated via an OpportunityContactRole?"

Comment: Yeah, I understand that now, but I didn't know that when I wrote the question originally and I think it's important to keep that in the question for posterity in case someone else runs into a similar issue. I never find it helpful when people go back on their questions and take out the things that led them to ask the question in the first place. I think I've noted my confusion in the answer.

Comment: Fair enough, I can see that, and I'm glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Here an approach to clarify things a bit and reduce confusion:

The concept of **WhoId** is limited to activities. It follows an quite untypical pattern of polymorphic relationships in salesforce which means the WhoId as reference can point to either a lead or a contact.

In almost all other cases you find the salesforce datamodels as strongly typed. Especially custom relationships are always pointing to a well defined object type.

An other polymorphic exception is e.g. the WhatId again on activities. Or the OwnerId of some standard and custom objects which can refer either to users or queues.

The relationship between contacts and accounts is non polymorphic. And so are the relationships between contact, OpportunityContactrlRoles and opportunity.

Lead is by design not related to account and opportunity because it represents an early phase in the salesprocess holding all information on a single entity before the conversion. This can indeed be a bit confusing for beginners.